# Sum of $ 1+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{9}+\frac{1}{16}+.....$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I know that the series b. converges as $\sum \frac{1}{n^p}$ converges for $p>1$, So a. also converges. I want to know the sum.

> > a.$1+\frac{1}{9}+\frac{1}{25}+\frac{1}{49}+.....$
> >
> > $b.1+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{9}+\frac{1}{16}+.....$

Comment: Write each series in summation form and use either the ratio or root tests.

Comment: Do you want the value of the sum or to know _where they are converging_ as you state in your question? They are two different things.

Answer (score 2):

If you know [$\displaystyle \sum_1^\infty \frac1{n^2} = \frac{\pi^2}6$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basel_problem), then this is easy, as the even series is just $\displaystyle \sum_1^\infty \frac1{4n^2} = \frac{\pi^2}{24}$.

I leave the odd series for you to separate out.

Answer (score 0):

The Riemann zeta function is defined as
$$\zeta(s) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^s}.$$
The value of $\zeta(2)$ is known to be $\frac{\pi^2}{6}$. Thus
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2} =  \frac{\pi^2}{6}.$$
The series in a. in your post can be written as
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2} - \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(2n)^2} =  \frac{3}{4}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2} = \frac{\pi^2}{8}.$$

Comment: How do you get $\pi/6$? Both sums are greater than $1$.

Comment: @MikePierce it is well known.

Comment: 1. Your sums should start at $n = 1$. 2. How are you deriving your expression for the series in part a? The series in part a appears to be $\sum_{n\textrm{ odd}}n^{-2}$, which is strictly less than $\zeta(2)$ (by comparison, all terms in the series of a appear in b, but not vice versa, and all are positive), but $1 + \pi/12 > \pi/6$. 3. @alephnull $\zeta(2)\neq\pi/6$, $\zeta(2) = \pi^2/6$.

Comment: Modified the answer. Please check your calculations before posting

Comment: How the value is to be known? What is the proof?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

$$1+\frac{1}{9}+\frac{1}{25}+\frac{1}{49}+\cdots=1+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{9}+\frac{1}{16}+\frac{1}{25}+\frac{1}{36}+\frac{1}{49}+\cdots-(\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{16}+\frac{1}{36}+\cdots)$$ Now $$\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{16}+\frac{1}{36}+\cdots=\frac{1}{4}(1+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{9}+\cdots)$$